# A property of exponential of operators 2

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, exponential-function, semigroup-of-operators, functional-calculus

Let $X$ be a Banach space. [The other day](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794435/a-property-of-exponential-of-operators) I asked if all bounded operators $A:X\to X$ satisfy the following property:

**(P)**: All bounded nonzero trajectories $t\mapsto e^{tA}x$ satisfy
$$\inf_{t\in \mathbb{R}}|e^{tA}x|>0,$$
where $x\in X$ and $e^{tA}$  is the exponential operator defined by $$e^{tA}:=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^kA^k}{k!}.$$
If the operator $A$ is scalar ($A=a\in \mathbb{R}$) or in general $A$ is a matrix  then  the property **(P)** holds as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761643/exponential-of-matrices-and-bounded-operators).
In infinite dimensions, there exist operators which do not satisfy this property [as explained by fedga](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794435/a-property-of-exponential-of-operators).
So later I observed that operators $A$ such that $t\mapsto e^{t A}$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ satisfy this property because
$$|x|=|e^{-tA}e^{tA}x|\leq\left(\sup_{t\in \mathbb{R}}|e^{-tA}|\right)|e^{tA}x|.$$
For operators such that $t\mapsto e^{tA}$ is not bounded in $t\in \mathbb{R}$, there's examples like: $A=iI$ or maybe $A$ is of finite rank (because it works for matrices).

So I just feel like if $t\mapsto e^{tA}$ is not bounded in $t$ and $A$ satisfies **(P)**, then $A$ must be of finite rank or something.

I don't know if this is true or not. I am also interested in "exponential" of unbounded operators or what it is known as strongly continuous groups of operators.